# How to make a filtration by a parameter in CommandText in C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I would like to fill a ComboBox but I want to sort data by one parameter called “id_group”.
I wrote a code but it does not work. 
In this line happens an exception which says “incorrect syntax” :

```
SqlDataReader sd = sc.ExecuteReader();
```

This is all my code:

```
int id_group=5;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand sc = conn.CreateCommand();
sc.CommandText = "SELECT STUDENT FROM FACULTY WHERE ID_GROUP '" + id_group + "'";
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader sd = sc.ExecuteReader(); //this happens exception - "incorrect syntax"
while (sd.Read())
{
    string graduate = (string)sd["STUDENT"];
    Student_comboBox.Items.Add(graduate);
}
conn.Close();
```

How to make it work?
Is there other ways to filter data by a parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually you are missing `=` on your query, so this should looked like this,

```
sc.CommandText = "SELECT STUDENT FROM FACULTY WHERE ID_GROUP = '" + 
                                                    id_group + "'";
```

but please do parameterize it to avoid `SQL Injection`

```
sc.CommandText = "SELECT STUDENT FROM FACULTY WHERE ID_GROUP = @groupID";
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groupID", id_group);
```

SOURCE

- [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)
- [Add (*recommended to use*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx)